# How do I get information from the view to the controller and back to another view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my project the user can search a category for flashcard sets from an external api. When the information is returned, the name of each set is displayed using an ng-repeat. I've also attached an ng-click function to the ng-repeat that copies the set id and that in turn sends out another $http get request that returns information about that particular set.

Here is the html:

```
<form ng-submit='getCategories(searchTerm)'>
  <input ng-model='searchTerm' placeholder="Search Categories">
</form>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat='name in categories' ng-click='getCategory(name.id)' ui-sref='category'>{{name.category}}</li>
</ul>
```

My problem is that when the user clicks on a set the view changes via ui-sref, the function fires the $http request and I can console log the information but it doesn't display on the new view. I understand that the controller 'refreshes' everytime the state changes but I don't know how to  overcome this.

Here is the controller:

```
angular.module('FlashCards').controller('categoryCtrl', function($scope, flashcard){

  $scope.getCategory = function(setId){
    flashcard.getCategoryById(setId)
    .then(function(response){
      $scope.category = response;
    })
  }

});
```

And here is the service:

```
angular.module('FlashCards').service('flashcard', function($http, $q){


  this.getCategoriesBySearch = function(searchTerm){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
     $http({
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://www.coursehero.com/api/flashcards/categories/?api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&starts_with=" + searchTerm
    }).then(function(response){
      deferred.resolve(response.data.data);
    })
    return deferred.promise;
  };

  this.getCategoryById = function(setId){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://www.coursehero.com/api/flashcards/categories/" + setId + "/sets/?api_key=YMBXVufy7GkBKoVE34SAMAZJfPVapK32"
    }).then(function(response){
      deferred.resolve(response.data.data);
    })
    return deferred.promise;
  };



});
```

Let me know if any part of the question needs a little more explaining. Thanks.

Comment: use the resolve property on the state defined to supply data to the controller on state change

Comment: Use 'resolve' property in StateProvider config file. have a look at [this(https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) link for help.

Comment: can you attach a plunkr for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using both `ng-click` and `ui-sref` on the same elements. Both are activated upon click and they don't have any implicit communication between them. Meaning that the result of function in `ng-click` isn't automatically sent to `ui-sref`.

There are multiple ways to overcome this problem. The best way is to use `resolve`. For this you'll need to make changes where you've defined the `category` state. The config should look something like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('category', {
    url: '/:categoryId/category',
    resolve: {
        category: ['flashcard', '$stateParams', function (flashcard, $stateParams) {
            return flashcard.getCategoryById($stateParams.categoryId);
        }]
    }
    /* Everything else you already have goes here... */
});
```

After this, you need to change your template to pass the `id` as a parameter to this state. Note that the job of fetching new data is moved to resolve and `ng-click` is no longer needed for that. This can look like:

```
<li ng-repeat='name in categories' ui-sref='category({categoryId: name.id})'>{{name.category}}</li>
```

Then, finally, in controller for the state where you're showing this data, you can inject `category` like you'd do for a service (`category` is what we resolved in the config) and it should get you the correct data.

If you don't want to do the resolve, you can remove the `ui-sref` from the template and instead, navigate to view from controller *after* you've got the http data. Place the navigation code in the `then` block.

Some theory: The use case of `resolve` is that you want to get something done after you try to navigate to a state and before that state loads. Everything you resolve will be injectable in the controller for the state you're resolving. Use it to do http, front-end caching and what-not. If resolve fails, the state will not be loaded. More info at [official docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider)